# How to use a user on different parts of an MVC?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

OK, I am building an MVC framework. Let's say for example, I have a SongsController. In a database, for each song I have the song's owner id (a user). What if I want to access the users information by getting the user id and selecting from the users table from that id and getting things such as name, email etc. I understand that there are joins, but for this example lets pretend there isn't any. What could I do? Could I create a UsersRepository class? Also, would I want to call it statically or create a new instance of it.

Comment: Actually Controllers doesn't be tied to the database. So whatever lives in your model doesn't need to be databasespecific. And is it really a worthwhile investment to do another MVC-framework?

Comment: I am grasping the OOP elements. I also want it to be my architecture so yes it is. @marko

Comment: You could query the user id (in your model) and then generate queries based on that.  However it seems tedious and like your overworking yourself.  This is an example of where a join works nicely for grabbing information off of multiple tables in one go, which sounds like is what you are trying to do.

Comment: OK, I'm just using this example because I feel like I will need to access different parts of the framework from another part. @Crackertastic

Comment: If I understand what you are trying to do, perhaps creating a session stable and storing what you need there?

Comment: Maybe you should try out codeigniter a little bit and look how they are doing it?

Comment: You should pass any data needed for a query to you model from your controller. The methods written in your model should accept the the data needed to run the query, and return it.  In you case you would pass the user to the model, or have the model call another function within itself with the user, then return the data.

Comment: But would if I want to access the User Model from say a posts controller? Is that ok? I see lots of people use the Repository design pattern, but don't know how to tie it in with this. @LaytonEverson

Comment: Yes, thats okay. The repository is just a collection of methods or functions for you model.

Comment: To quickly answer your question you would go to the users model for a list of users you want to use, then you would go to the songs model and pass the users to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a multiple ways to structure this.

For instance, you could use a UserModel, which is an object representing the user table.
This object does not provide any functions to launch queries with joins.

Then you could add a repository class, which provides additional functions related to queries, spanning over multiple tables (with joins).

- UserModel

  - getUserName($userId)
- UsersRepository

  - getSongsOfUser($userId)

You can think of this as:

- the UserModel being "object 2 table" and
- the UserRepository being "object 2 tables".

--

How to work with Models in the Controller? Should i call them statically or dynamically?

The general rule applies: avoid static functions in OOP. So: instantiate your models.

```
$userRepo = new UserRepository();
$result = $userRepo->getSongsOfUser($userId);
```

This is mainly because static stuff is really hard to test. 
A static function is isolated and you have to pull all the depenencies in, for example the database instance. This leads to other static functions calls, like Database::getInstance() or to static properties access, which has to be populated (somehow, somewhere, before). You see, this gets messy really fast. This often leads to poorly designed spaghetti code applications, where procedural code sauce is mixed with object oriented noodles. Such an architecture is hard to maintain and it's hard to implement new features.

If this is just a hobby project, then `$result = UserRepository::getSongsOfUser($userId);` would suffice.

Comment: Instantiating the repository in the controller using `new` is basically no better than using a static method. The controller is still tightly coupled to it. He should be using a factory. Also, having the controller fetch data and bind it to the template, as well as update the model breaks SRP. Controllers shouldn't be fetching data, that's the views job. Do not go the CodeIgniter/CakePHP/OpenCart etc way.

Comment: He could use a factory. But it's a design decision that depends on what he is trying to accomplish. He could also use a dependency injection library with auto-wiring. But that is way above, what he asked. -- Regarding your statement, that Controllers should not fetch data, but the view should. This works, for sure - but is wrong in my opinion. Because, then, the view knows the model and calls the repository methods, right? And that's a violation of the view dumbness principle. The view should not know about the model at all. It should be dumb, just accepting data and not fetch data itself.

Comment: Where's this "view dumbness principle" stated? CodeIgniter, CakePHP, OpenCart and all of those have "view dumbness" and it leads to controllers doing presentation layer work like setting titles, fetching data, selecting templates, passing data to templates and more. This is strictly view layer work so why is a controller doing it? If you have a complex search with pagination now your controller extracts all the search filters, validates them, calculates pages, fetches data, passes data to template and more. That's all presentation layer related stuff so why would it be stuffed in a controller?

Comment: Pagination is for presentation purposes to make it easier to view large data sets, therefore it goes in the view. A view is not a template, a view is an object that has methods just like your controller has methods. Templates are dumb yes but views are not. The view fetches its own data and passes it to the template. CI, Cake, OpenCart and many more call templates views. I see it time and time again in those frameworks, they have no real view, only templates, so all presentation layer work gets stuff into the controller which ends up being complicated, doing too much and majorly breaking SRP.

Comment: The view is only about display of information; any changes to the information are handled by the third member of the MVC trinity: the controller. The controller causes the view to update. There are two important separation principles here: the presentation is separated from the model and the controller is separated from the view. The first one is more important in my eyes. Frameworks like Zend, Symfony or Yii provide Helpers functions which assist in handling view transformations. Your SRP concern is valid, but SRP simply doesn't fit MVC.

Comment: Using your pagination example: The controller knows via the request which segment of data to get. This request must be filtered and validated by a Service, before you start working with it. This happens before the data reaches an ActionController or PageController. Then the request data is passed to the model to get the result set. The pages calculation might happen in the model or in a Service layer. The results are then pushed from the controller to the view, which applies content transformations based on the response type, often via ViewHelpers.

Comment: @Jens-AndréKoch that is completely wrong. View **is not** a dumb template. Instead it is the part of MVC triad, which is responsible for UI logic.

Comment: @tereško Well, it depends! It's actually an architecture decision, which you have to make. And alternative paradigms are always possible. Some people prefer to have views pulling data from a model layer, while others prefer pushing data to the view. I guess, today a mix of both strategies is used.

Comment: If you want a different paradigm, then stop calling it MVC. I would recommend calling it "rails-like" then.

Comment: Yes, i can live with that. And i guess your approach is more Smalltalk-MVC or IBM MVP (model-view-presenter) like, right?

Comment: @Jens-AndréKoch I used to do it that way but I have since learned better and will never go back. What you are really doing is Model Template Controller, like most of the PHP frameworks. Since there's no view the code/UI logic that's supposed to be in the view has to go somewhere and unfortunately the natural thing to do is push it into controllers and the model(evident from your comments above) and sometimes even pushing it to random layers in the application all because there is no view, only dumb templates. Symfony is not MVC they even state it, they work on a simple request/response cycle.